# Embedding an OpenID Connect-secured site in an iframe

Tags: security, authentication, iframe, web, openid-connect

I need to embed a third party website in an iframe and the site is using OpenID Connect for user authentication. That would mean that when the iframe loads, there'll be redirects to the provider and back, inside the iframe. Sometimes the provider may redirect back silently, and sometimes it might wish to authenticate the user and show them the login page before redirecting back.

Will this work in practice? Do providers forbid showing their login page in iframes for security reasons? What if there's no need for the provider to authenticate the user at the moment, will the silent redirect work? Or do providers forbid even that?